# How do I get out of depression

Tags: cognitive-psychology, depression

*(Please do not downvote me. if you think this is wrong place to ask such question here then suggest me where I can ask and I will move question there.)*

**About me:**
I am a software engineer in Pakistan and a victim of depression for the last 6 years, and I am 22 now.

**How my depression started:**
This thing started when I was 16-17 and I used to like a girl. She got married. This thing has stuck in my mind and I cannot get out of it.

I got very skinny after 16 and so I am now, people call me skinny before they say HI to me, and I feel so bad(but I don't express it).

My parents and relatives always said `You cannot do this` whatever I said or tried to do, *this is how i grew up*

**What I have become:**

I had thought of committing suicide several times but did not.

My family, friends(I have very few friends as I don't make much) and relatives love me but I do not like to talk anyone, even I don't like my parents and family.

I just want to stay alone or want to sleep.

And it does not matter if I get to bed at 10 or 02:00 AM, I end up sleep by 03:00 AM.

I have much money than the friends but I don't have any hobby or interest to spend on.

I told my mom twice, I thought she would understand my mental condition but, she laughed at me :(

Comment: I am sorry you are having this trouble!  Questions about the behavior of an individual are off-topic here, as it is neither safe nor a good idea to give medical or psychiatric advice with so little information.  Please talk to a psychiatrist or a mental health counsellor--I hope you get the help you need!

Comment: You might want to rephrase this question to something more like "How can a depressed individual get out of depression?" or "Can a depressed individual get out of depression by him/herself?".
Other than that, your question is too specific for a topic here.

Comment: Read the following meta-analysis:
Meditation Programs for Psychological Stress and Well-being
A Systematic Review and Meta-analysis
Sonal Singh, MD, MPH1; Erica M. S. Sibinga, MD, MHS2; Neda F. Gould, PhD3; Anastasia Rowland-Seymour, MD1; Ritu Sharma, BSc4; Zackary Berger, MD, PhD1; Dana Sleicher, MS, MPH3; David D. Maron, MHS4; Hasan M. Shihab, MBChB, MPH4; Padmini D. Ranasinghe, MD, MPH1; Shauna Linn, BA4; Shonali Saha, MD2; Eric B. Bass, MD, MPH1,4; Jennifer A. Haythornthwaite, PhD
Concerning physical exercise:
http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00702-008-0092-x

Comment: **Use a search engine or telephone directory to find a psychotherapist or psychiatrist and seek help.** You are a wonderful person who has been taught to feel bad about himself and a professional can help you undo this. Quick self-help: Eat a spoonful of sugar. It works as an antidepressant. Do not drink any alcohol. Eat and drink healthy food. Do half an hour of endurance sport (e.g. long distance running) three times a week. Force yourself if you have to. It relaxes your sympatic nervous system and reduces emotional tension. Good luck.